# How to use celery with django duration field

Tags: python, django, django-models, celery, django-celery

I have model `Banner` with `duration` field. I wanna update value of `status` field of banner after end of duration. For example, I'm creating object with hour duration, and I need to create task which will change value of `status` field after hour. How can I do this celery?

```
# models.py

class AdvertisementModelMixin(models.Model):
    class Statuses(models.TextChoices):
        ACTIVE = "active", _("Active")
        HIDDEN = "hidden", _("Hidden")
        DELETED = "deleted", _("Deleted")
        TEST = "test", _("Test")

    link = models.URLField()
    view_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    age_from = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        blank=True, null=True, validators=[MaxValueValidator(80)])
    age_to = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        blank=True, null=True, validators=[MaxValueValidator(80)])
    devices = models.ManyToManyField(Device, verbose_name="platforms",)
    duration = models.DurationField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=Statuses.choices, default=Statuses.ACTIVE)
```